# Vue.js 2 - Bootstrap 4

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to understand how t use the standard Bootstrap 4 css with a vue.js app..
I set up a simple test project using vue-cli webpack , and copied a standard Bootstrap navbar in a header component.
It displays BUT no links are visible ....

[image: screenshot]

added into **package.json**

```
 "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.3",
```

added into **main.js**

```
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <myheader></myheader>
    <div class="container">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myheader from '@/components/Header'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: { myheader }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
  <header id="myheader">
    <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded rounded ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerNavbar" aria-controls="containerNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="containerNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>z
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
import router from '@/router/index'
export default {
  name: 'myheader',
  router
}
</script>

<style>
</style>

**UPDATE**
```

I added jQuery and popper.js with npm
and updated my **webpack.dev.config**

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

I also updated my **.eslintrc**

```
  globals: {
    "$": true,
    "jQuery": true
   },
```

Now the Bootstrap navbar collapse runs correctly , but still no horizontal links...

[image: navbar display]

Comment: Bootstrap 4, afaik, requires jQuery. Are you loading `jquery.js` and `boostrap.js` in your application? usually, to use jQuery with view-model frameworks such as vue is considered a bad idea, that's why some people made specific Vue implementations for bootstrap, like https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/. Are you sure you just need a standard bootstrap?

Comment: God No ! ... it was not necessary with bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: You can get most of boostrap to work without javascript, but to get it all, you need `bootstrap.js, which relies upon `jquery`. As far as I know, bootstrap vs4 also needs jquery (from here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: thanks a lot...  it's only a test , so I'll get jquey in it... but I guess it would be better to move on Bootstrap-vue for better integration with vue.js ( if Bootstrap is a client requirement of course ... )

Comment: CSS would never be dependent on a javascript library. Personally, I import Bootstrap 4 SCSS files into a global `app.scss`, not via Vue itself. I just always found that easier.

Comment: Why not just use [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/).  I believe it's goal is to provide Bootstrap components and replace the bits that need jQuery with Vue implementations.

Comment: @erwin could you eventually resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Some of Bootstrap v4 [requires a DOM API wrapping library like jQuery to function](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js):

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages,
>   right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come
>   first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.
>
> We use jQuery’s slim build, but the full version is also supported.

This is also the case with [Bootstrap v3](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#whats-included):

> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included,
>   as shown in the starter template. Consult our bower.json to see which
>   versions of jQuery are supported.

Although a lot of Bootstrap can get used without any JavaScript, some components like dropdowns, alert dismissing, and other cross-cutting widgets need the extra power that JavaScript provides.  You can probably get away without it if you are just using the grid system.

---

However, if you would rather not explicitly depend on jQuery, you could try [Vue Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) which is a Vue plugin that provides most of the Bootstrap components and wraps the things that jQuery is necessary for in a Vue oriented way.

Comment: Thanks zero298 for your feedback... As I've been asked to talk about Vue.js, I intend first to show how to use standard Bootstrap.jQuery libs.. then after components introduction, I'll switch to Bootstrap-vue, so people will understand it...

Comment: I added sucessfully jQuery, popper.js and Bootstrap l, updated webpack config... but still getting some issues... see updated question..

Answer (score 0):

As Bootsrap4 is still in beta (3) I am using in my test the wrong standard classes, I rather should use :

```
 nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
```

up and running now ....